# Zoom to certain domain?

Tags: d3.js

I have a time scale for x axis and every time I zoom, I save the transform object and the new time scale. They are `this.scale` and `this.transform`. Here `this` is a VueJs instance.

I want to implement a function that changes the zoom to certain area but I have no idea how to calculate the new `k` and new `x`. In my situation, zoom is applied only for the axis x.

Here is my code :

```
const k = this.w / (this.scale(dateTimeEnd) - this.scale(dateTimeStart)) * (this.transform ? this.transform.k : 1);

const translateX = (this.transform ? this.transform.x : 0) - this.scale(dateTimeStart);

this.svg
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .call(this.zoom.transform, () => {
        return d3.zoomIdentity
            .scale(k)
            .translate(translateX, 0);
    });
```

`this.svg` is the selection with the zoom behaviour bound to it.

How do I calculate the new `k` indicator for scale and the new `x` for translateX ?